# How can i keep class that extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivty?

Tags: proguard

How can i keep class that extends FragmentActivty ?
I used -keep public class * extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
after that the class exists but when i start the application it doesn't work and i have an error that he can't find the class